# How could I get stars in the SERPs without structured data?

Tags: google-search, search-results

I was looking at a website that has achieved stars in the SERPs. When I ran the URL in [Googles Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/) all they had was Breadcrumbs, Organization and WebSite types. Non of these had any rating mark-up.

They do however have a 3rd party reviews widget on the site.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: There is no possible way for us to know. There is not enough information for us to even guess. That said, some businesses use Google+ and the reviews from the Google+ business profile are used in a variety of ways within the SERPs. This is likely where the reviews come from.

Comment: What information do you need? They don't have any rating structured data and the only thing that refers to ratings is the widget. The 3rd party review is reviews.co.uk. They do have ratings on google+ but nowhere near the 300+ users that is showing in the SERPs. The number of users is very close to the number of users on their third party page.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way of getting stars in the SERPs without using microdata.   Can you give us the link to the search and site that you found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found out that there are certain trusted 3rd party sites that when using their widgets can gain you stars.

I also know that Trust Pilot offers the opportunity to get stars for 5 pages to their customers.

Answer (score -2):

It's better to use rating structured data from schema.org since Google recommends it to use.

Comment: Such a short answer is not high quality.   A better answer would explain why you think this is true.   Do you have personal experience?   Can you link to references that support your position?